# Report.phtml and store not loading

Tags: magento-1.7, error, template, magento-community, phtml

I'm using `Magento 1.7` on WAMP server. I can't access my store. I can't access the admin panel neither.

Instead of loading the store, the page shown is the content defined under `/error/CUSTOM_THEME/report.phtml`.

I checked `app/etc/local.xml`, I have access to the database via `phpMyAdmin`, and I deleted `var/cache` and `var/session`. I have no `maintenance.flag`, this is not the problem.

I don't know why my store is not loading. Any ideas on what could be causing that?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you removed the maintenance if statement from your index.php file and now it is getting triggered even without the maintenance flag file. I can post a more accurate answer if you add your index.php code to the question